# style.css not reflecting changes. I have no cache installed

Tags: themes

I have edited the style.css of my theme but no changes are reflecting. There is no caching plugin at all.

Even when I delete the style.css nothing happens. Could this be the server caching, it's on  hostgator?

Thanks.

Comment: Clear your browser cache!

Comment: Did that already ctrl + F5 quite a few times

Comment: If I view source, my extra css is not in the style.css

Comment: Check headers with firebug. If 304 - not modified then this is caching.

Comment: Thanks Simon for the header tip. Not caching though :)

Answer (score 1):

When it happens to me it usually turns out that I'm editing the wrong file. Are you sure the active theme is the one you are editing? You should go to your admin and check. If you really deleted the right CSS file your theme should become inactive and listed as a broken theme

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure :) I'm also changing the template files and that works.

Comment: Yes true it should remove styles from the theme when deleted. I uploaded the file once, it worked and showed the styles. but after a refresh again the styles vanished again. Then I went and overwrite the file and still no changes. Will have a look later if it's not my fault :) it was very late.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the top of your css ?
Edit to suit your custom theme.

```
/*   
Theme Name: Theme name
Theme URI: http://www.yourdomain.com
Description: jQuery 1.7.1 / jQuery Mobile 1.2.
Author: Meias Safa
Author URI: http://www.yourdomain.com
Version: 1.0
*/
```

Put this at the top of your style.css!

Then deactivate and reactivate your theme, that usually works.

Comment: I changed the version on mine, deactivated and reactivated.  No luck for me.  This is incredibly frustrating.  I may go back to custom development from scratch.  This is for the birds.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it could be. I use HostGator too but there's no server caching on my account. You can chat with them online on their site, they've got great support.